# UIBezierPath for Rounding Corner of Button not work properly

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I made a class for UIButton and override awakeFromNib.
Next (GREEN BUTTON) use this class.

I have some space in right of Next button (Green one). this space will be more in iPad:

[image: next button]

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.TopLeft, .BottomLeft], cornerRadii: CGSizeMake(5, 5))

    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    maskLayer.path = path.CGPath
    self.layer.mask = maskLayer

    self.layer.borderColor = MyColor.nextButtonBorder.CGColor
}
```

Comment: Add this code in viewDidAppear method

Comment: Nope, This is in class NextButton: UIButton { ... } and I set next button to this class in Interface Builder

Comment: May be issue of Auto layout not set properly

Comment: No, I tried in new Empty ViewController and set left , right top constraint but still It's not OK. => https://i.imgsafe.org/1ad015924c.png

Answer (score 0):

You should put this code in

```
layoutSubviews()
```

method. Don't forget to delete previous added maskLayer.

Full example:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    self.layer.mask = nil
    let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.TopLeft, .BottomLeft], cornerRadii: CGSizeMake(5, 5))

    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    maskLayer.path = path.CGPath
    self.layer.mask = maskLayer

    self.layer.borderColor = MyColor.nextButtonBorder.CGColor
}
```

Comment: I tested this way but on rotation button will be failed.